# firebug find javascript function source

Tags: javascript, firebug

With firebug, I'm having a difficult time locating jspaginate.init Javascript function in page https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7629335. This is in reference to [How to I find javascript source in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935941/how-to-i-find-javascript-source-in-web-page)

I've gotten this far.  Now, how do I go about finding the function?

[image]

Here is the list of whatever they are that I see:
[image: list of whatever they are that I see]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find js function with firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469691/find-js-function-with-firebug)

Answer (score 1):

Click the script tab.  Type in the name in the search file.  In this case, type jspaginate.

When you click on the search field, a pull down menu appears. Be sure that "multiple files" is checked.  Should search as you type. Doesn't tell you if multiple items have been found.  You need to click on the down arrow until you find the function jspaginate. [image]

[image]